# How to set a flag due to multi group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I've a query that return (with some join/logis/different tables):

```
SELECT WorkTypeId, WorktypeWorkID, LevelID
    FROM Worktypes as w
    LEFT JOIN WorktypesWorks as ww on w.ID = ww.WorktypeID
    LEFT JOIN WorktypesWorksLevels as wwl on ww.ID = wwl.WorktypeWorkID
    ORDER BY w.ID, ww.ID, wwl.LevelID
```

This is the result:

```
WorkTypeId  WorktypeWorkID  LevelID
1           1               1
1           1               2
1           1               3
1           2               1
1           2               2
1           2               3
1           3               1
1           4               1
1           4               2
1           5               1
4           6               1
4           7               1
4           7               2
4           7               3
```

I'd like, for each row, add an additional column (i.e. called IsLast), which return true if, for each WorkTypeId group, the (**first**) subgroup WorktypeWorkID contains the smaller LevelID.

In the example above, the result should be:

```
WorkTypeId  WorktypeWorkID  LevelID IsLast
1           1               1       false
1           1               2       false
1           1               3       false
1           2               1       false
1           2               2       false
1           2               3       false
1           3               1       true
1           4               1       false
1           4               2       false
1           5               1       false
4           6               1       true
4           7               1       false
4           7               2       false
4           7               3       false
```

How can I do it? Basically:

- group by WorktypeWorkID getting the MAX LevelId and take first
- group by WorkTypeId getting the MIX LevelId from prev groups
- add the flag

Comment: @DaleK I've written my attempt

Comment: Can't see a query in your question? And you have high enough rep to know how to write a good question.

Comment: @DaleK: I've added the query. Not sure why this help, but ok ;)

Comment: You can already see why it helps, you've just had to ask Gordon to modify his answer to match your query - which you wouldn't have had to do if otherwise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the smallest `WorktypeWorkID` which contains only row.  If so:

```
select t.*,
       (case when cnt = 1 and
                  dense_rank() over (partition by WorkTypeId, cnt order by WorktypeWorkID) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as islast
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by WorkTypeId, WorktypeWorkID) as cnt
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: I've added the query that retrieve the result. Can you adjust this partition code with that query? Thanks

Comment: Just use a CTE . . . `with t as (<your query here>)`.